# Admin Directory API/Admin SDK - Renaming Google Users

Tags: sdk, google-admin-sdk

I'm in the process of renaming all users in our Google Suite due to an agency rebranding. I'm following [this Google guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7068037?hl=en).

At the last step, where the Actions menu should appear, however, it never actually appears. Both Admin Directory API and Google Admin SDK have been enabled.
It's been just about 24 hours, so I think it should have been propagated by now.

Any thoughts?

Comment: First you have to take note that you must be logged in as a [super administrator](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986#super_admin). Also, you have to consider the [Impact of changing a username](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2622985), maybe this article could help you identify what's wrong when you are [renaming a user](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182084). Also, you need to take note that there is a [limits and quotas](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits#api-limits-and-quotas) in every call you make using the API.

Comment: Thanks for this info. However, I am aware of the implications of renaming users. My question is how do I get the Actions menu to appear.